# How to fix skew trapezoidal distribution sampling output sample size

Tags: algorithm, matlab, math, distribution, skew

I am trying to generate a skewed trapezoidal distribution using inverse transform sampling.
The inputs are the values where the ramps start and end (a, b, c, d) and the sample size.

```
a=-3;b=-1;c=1;d=8; 
SampleSize=10e4;
h=2/(d+c-a-b);
```

Then I calculate the ratio of the length of ramps and flat components to get sample size for each:

```
firstramp=round(((b-a)/(d-a)),3);
flat=round((c-b)/(d-a),3);
secondramp=round((d-c)/(d-a),3);
n1=firstramp*SampleSize; %sample size for first ramp
n3=secondramp*SampleSize; %sample size for second ramp
n2=flat*SampleSize;
```

And then finally I get the histogram from the following code:

```
quartile1=h/2*(b-a);
quartile2=1-h/2*(d-c);

y1=linspace(0,quartile1,n1);
y2=linspace(quartile1,quartile2,n2);
y3=linspace(quartile2,1,n3);

%inverse cumulative distribution functions
invcdf1=a+sqrt(2*(b-a)/h)*sqrt(y1);
invcdf2=(a+b)/2+y2/h;
invcdf3=d-sqrt(2*(d-c)/h)*sqrt(1-y3);

distr=[invcdf1 invcdf2 invcdf3];

histogram(distr,100)
```

However the sampling of ramps and flat components are not equal, looks like this:

[image: Messed up output]

I fixed this by trial and error, by reducing the sample size of the ramps by half:

```
n1=0.5*firstramp*SampleSize; %sample size for first ramp
n3=0.5*secondramp*SampleSize; %sample size for second ramp
n2=flat*SampleSize;
```

This made the distribution look like this:

[image: Fixed Distribution]

However this makes the output sample less than what is given in input.

I've also tried different combinations of changing the sample sizes of ramps and flat.
This also works:

```
n1=0.75*firstramp*SampleSize; %sample size for first ramp
n3=0.75*secondramp*SampleSize; %sample size for second ramp
n2=1.5*flat*SampleSize;
```

It increases the output samples, but it's still not close.

Any help will be appreciated.

Full code:

```
a=-3;b=-1;c=1;d=8; 
SampleSize=10e4;%*1.33333333333333;
h=2/(d+c-a-b);
firstramp=round(((b-a)/(d-a)),3);
flat=round((c-b)/(d-a),3);
secondramp=round((d-c)/(d-a),3);

n1=firstramp*SampleSize; %sample size for first ramp
n3=secondramp*SampleSize; %sample size for second ramp
n2=flat*SampleSize;

quartile1=h/2*(b-a);
quartile2=1-h/2*(d-c);

y1=linspace(0,quartile1,.75*n1);
y2=linspace(quartile1,quartile2,1.5*n2);
y3=linspace(quartile2,1,.75*n3);

%inverse cumulative distribution functions
invcdf1=a+sqrt(2*(b-a)/h)*sqrt(y1);
invcdf2=(a+b)/2+y2/h;
invcdf3=d-sqrt(2*(d-c)/h)*sqrt(1-y3);

distr=[invcdf1 invcdf2 invcdf3];

histogram(distr,100)
%end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Matlab so I was hoping somebody else would jump in on this, but since nobody did here goes.

If I'm reading your code correctly what you did is not an inversion.  Inversion is 1-1, i.e., one uniform input produces one outcome.  You seem to be using a technique known as the "composition method".  In composition the overall distribution is comprised of component pieces, each of which is straightforward to generate.  You choose which component to generate from based on their proportions/probabilities relative to the whole.  For density functions, probability is found as the area under the density curve, so your first mistake was in sampling the components relative to the width of each component rather than using their areas.  The correct sampling proportions are 2/13, 4/13, and 7/13 for what you designated the `firstramp`, `flat`, and `secondramp` components, respectively. A second mistake (which is relatively minor) was to assign exact sample sizes to each of the components.  Having probability 2/13 does not mean that exactly `2*SampleSize/13` of your samples will be from the `firstramp`, it means that's the expected sample size for that component.  The expected value of a random variate is not necessarily (or even likely to be) the outcome you will actually get.

In pseudocode, the composition approach would be

```
generate U ~ Uniform(0,1)
if U <= 2/13:
   generate and return a value from firstramp
else if U <= 6/13:
   generate and return a value from flat
else:
   generate and return a value from secondramp
```

Note that since each of the `generate` options will use one or more uniforms, and choosing between the options requires a uniform `U`, this is not an inversion.

If you want an actual inversion, you need to quantify your density, integrate it to get the cumulative distribution function, then apply the inversion technique by setting `F(X) = U` and solving for `X`.  Since your distribution is made of distinct components, both the density and cumulative density will be piecewise functions.

After deriving the height based on the requirement that the areas of the two triangles and the flat section must add up to 1, I came up with the following for your density:

```
       | (x + 3) / 13       -3 <= x <= -1
       |
f(x) = | 2 / 13             -1 <= x <= 1
       |
       | 2 * (8 - x) / 91    1 <= x <= 8
```

Integrating this and collecting terms produces the CDF:

```
       | (x + 3)**2 / 26                    -3 <= x <= -1
       |
F(x) = | (2 + x) * 2 / 13                   -1 <= x <= 1
       |
       | 6 / 13 + [49 - (x - 8)**2] / 91     1 <= x <= 8
```

Finally, determining the values of F(x) at the break points between the segments and applying inversion yields the following pseudocode algorithm:

```
generate U ~ Uniform(0,1)
if U <= 2 / 13:
    return 2 * sqrt( (13 * U) / 2 ) - 3
else if U <= 6 / 13:
    return (13 * U) / 2 - 2:
else:
    return 8 - sqrt( 91 * (1 - U) )
```

Note that this is a true inversion.  The outcome is determined by generating a single U, and transforming it in different ways depending on which range it falls in.